# How do I control the width and height of the <audio> tag?

Tags: html

//I want to change the size of  acording to the 'height' and 'width' properties
//however,it does't work.

```
    <audio autoplay  controls   height="100px" width="100px">
    <source  src="周杰伦-天台的月光.flac">
    </audio>
```

Comment: Those are not supported tags for the element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio. Try styling it with CSS

Answer (score 0):

You might specify that using `style` attribute, for example if you want 500px wide and 100px tall element you might do

```
<audio controls style="width:500px;height:100px">
<source src="sound.flac">
</audio>
```

Comment: Thank you, friend.It is amazing.some tags  require  `style` to change the width and height .I changed the width of the <audio> in your way.  But it seems that the height of this tags   cannot be changed .